How to AutoComplete a combobox with values ​containing a string?
I need the values ​​that CONTAINS the typed string to appear in the autocomplete list of a combobox and not those that begin with said string. I am using a form in a Desktop Application with VS 2022 and C#. Could someone help me please? Thank you
